# Regualr expression for google Sheet Find and Replace

Tags: google-sheets, nsregularexpression

I have some rows in some columns contains something like

- #Invalid Ref: 234566
- #Invalid Ref: 123445
- #Invalid Ref: 235678

I am trying to use find and replace by regular expression to find any row that contains any of the above and replace it with empty

what is the best regular expression I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the last numbers are always six digits, this should work. See [google's explanation for Regex Find Replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?visit_id=637887918864599809-2077775799&p=spreadsheets_find_replace&rd=1#zippy=%2Csee-an-example) for more examples.

```
^#Invalid Ref: [0-9]{6}$
```

[image]

Comment: Bless Your Hands

Comment: uuhhh thanks. One doesn't hear that a lot on SO! =)